# Installer crash when i tried to install 12.04 on my macbook Pro 7.1

Tags: 12.04, installation, apple, macbook-pro

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 several times on my macbookpro 7.1 but each times it crashed.
I burned a liveCD - desktop 64bits, and launched it. It works well
I can use the LiveCD as normal but when i want to install it crash after click on "Next" on this screen : http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/extra/LINUX/large/ubuntu1204installation-large_002.jpg

I tried weeks ago i get the same issue, now i downloaded & burn the actual ISO and got the same problem.

Any clue to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some oddities  that make installation on Macs different from installation on a PC's

First make sure you downloaded and are using the mac iso http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/

This is only current for 11.10 but it may also help  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro7-1/Oneiric

Comment: I downloaded the amd64+mac iso which seems to be fit to use on a mac architecture....
Well, i don't really want to install à 11.10 and upgrade it, it will take times and will not give ma very clean system...

Comment: Read this http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/index.html

Comment: I've never used the mac specific cd:s for installation on my macbook pro. I Have a macbook 5.1.

Can you paste the error message or logs related to the crash?

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing you're using lion on your mac. check out this website. 
 http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1908210

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.